# Why Selenium WebDriver resolves promise for get() when page did not load

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am using selenium-webdriver in version 3.4.0. The below code prints success even though Chrome cannot not load page, because server listening on port 3333 is not started yet.

```
const selenium = require('selenium-webdriver');
const webdriver = new selenium.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
webdriver.get('http://localhost:3333').then(() => console.log('success'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation (http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#selenium-webdriver-api-commands-and-operations):

```
Dependent on several factors, including the OS/Browser combination,
WebDriver may or may not wait for the page to load. In some 
circumstances, WebDriver may return control before the page has
finished, or even started, loading. To ensure robustness, you need to wait
for the element(s) to exist in the page using Explicit and Implicit Waits.
```

So, you will want to either invoke the wait callback directly or create a promise to do so:

```
webdriver.wait(function() {
    webdriver.get('http://localhost:3333').then(() => console.log('success'));
}, timeout);
```

I leave using a promise to do so as an exercise to be implemented.

Comment: You are right, when I use firefox driver promise is rejected. However code you included is wrong - we have to wait for existence of some element on the page i.e.: `webdriver.get('http://localhost:3333')
      .then(() => webdriver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('nav'))));`

Answer (score -1):

Set wait time like 5 seconds to load the page or to start the server.

```
webdriver.implicitly_wait(5);
```

Comment: Page cannot get loaded, because server does not work. Problem is that Selenium gives a wrong feedback - success instead of failure.